# why is Development in Magento 2 EE so slow?

Tags: magento-2.0

when applying changes in the development, it takes like 15 minutes to regenerate the PUB so I can test the implemented solution.
When changing classes, we would need to regenerate the "Generation" file too

And in general, development tends to be really slow when developing in Magento 2 EE. As strange as it may sound when developing in Magento 2 CE this problem does not appear present.

Any advices on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In M2, you have different modes of development.

I recommend you work with developer mode.

You have a official doc here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

Comment: If we turn it into Production it runs a lot faster..
BUT Since we are developing software it is running on Developer mode.. and it takes a lot of time to even display the changes in the browser.. Core i5, 8GB RAM and non SSD Hard Drive..

Comment: Working in VM or M/W/XAMP ? I'm working with same hardware in Mac Book Pro without Docker,Vagrant and works fine

Comment: MAMP Installation.. it works a little faster
On LAMP Configurations it is not moving fast.. it takes a lot of time to render changes in the browser and so on.. any tips are mostly welcome